# Inheritage from ndarray calls __getitem__

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I'm trying to derive a class from ndarray. I'm sticking to the recipe found in [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) but I get an error I do not understand, when I override a `__getiem__()` function. I'm sure this is how it is supposed to work but I do not understand how to do it correctly. My class that basically adds a "dshape" property looks like:

```
class Darray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, dshape, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.SelObj = SelObj
        obj.dshape = dshape
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'dshape', 'N')  

    def __getitem__(self, index):        
        return self[index]
```

when I now try to do:

```
D = Darray( ones((10,10)), ("T","N"))
```

the interpreter will fail with a maximum depth recursion, because he calls `__getitem__` over and over again.

can someone explain to me why and how one would implement a getitem function?

cheers,
David

Comment: As a side note, you probably don't actually _want_ to implement a custom `__getitem__` on an `ndarray`, because (unless you just pass straight through, or code exactly the same thing as the base class) ufuncs/broadcasting won't see your array the same way that indexing it does. So, what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: That sounds intriguing, might I ask you or anyone to elaborate on that topic or to save you time to point to a reference on that matter? I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> can someone explain to me why and how one would implement a getitem function?

For your current code, a `__getitem__` isn't needed. Your class works fine (except for the undefined `SelObj`) when I remove the `__getitem__` implementation.

The reason for the maximum recursion depth error is the definition of `__getitem__`, which uses `self[index]`: a shorthand notation for `self.__getitem__(index)`. If you must override `__getitem__`, then make sure you call the superclass implementation of `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return super(Darray, self).__getitem__(index)
```

As for why you'd do this: there are lots of reasons for overriding this function, e.g. you might associate names with the rows of an array:

```
class NamedRows(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, rows, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = np.asarray(*args, **kwargs).view(cls)
        obj.__row_name_idx = dict((n, i) for i, n in enumerate(rows))
        return obj

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, basestring):
            idx = self.__row_name_idx[idx]
        return super(NamedRows, self).__getitem__(idx)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = NamedRows(["foo", "bar"], [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
>>> a["foo"]
NamedRows([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):        
    return self[index]
```

`foo[index]` just calls `foo.__getitem__(index)`. But in your case, that just returns `foo[index]`, which just calls `foo.__getitem__(index)`. Which repeats in an infinite loop until you run out of stack space.

If you want to defer to your parent class, you have to do this:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):        
    return super(Darray, self)[index]
```

… or, maybe more explicitly:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):        
    return super(Darray, self).__getitem__(index)
```

Comment: thanks your answer also gave the right explanation, but I hope you won't mind accepting the latter one for the included example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to inherit a class from `np.ndarray` type. You can implement the same idea as above with the standard OOP approach. The following example does the same thing as your code, but more elegent. Instead of subclassing, I am just treating the numpy array as a member of my special object that also contains `dshape`. It simply creates `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` to behave exactly like we would subscript a `np.ndarray` object.

```
class Darray:
    def __init__(self, input_array, dshape):
        self.array = np.array(input_array)
        self.dshape = dshape

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.array[item]

    def __setitem__(self, item, val):
        self.array[item] = val
```

Now you can write further methods to describe the exact behaviour that you want. Whatever `dhape` was supposed to do to the inherited array, now to do to `self.array` member.

The added benefit of this approach is that there is no headache of recursion depth, or `__array_finalize__`, or `super()`, or any other pitfalls that can occur in this process of subclassing and overloading. There is always a simpler way for intended use cases.

Edit: In my example above, the `__getitem__` method does not work for `,` separated indices for `N` dimensional arrays. A fix for that,

```
    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        return self.array.__getitem__(*args)
```